# Remove Underline on Hover

Tags: css, hyperlink, shopify, underline

I've tried everything I could to remove the underline that appears when hovering over a product title on my Shopify. Any css suggestions as to how I can remove this underline anywhere that a product title appears?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you provide code or link to the issue?

Comment: Hey @MinalChauhan ! Right now it looks like the code that is on our Shopify's theme.scss for text links is:                                                                                    
  .text-link {
  display: inline;
  border: 0 none;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; }

.text-link--accent {
  color: var(--color-btn-primary);
  border-bottom: 1px solid currentColor;
  padding-bottom: 1px; }
  .text-link--accent:not([disabled]):hover, .text-link--accent:focus {
    color: var(--color-btn-primary-focus); }

Answer (score 1):

```
**Try these two**

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: hm for some reason that didn't seem to work, i tried something like that earlier and it still wouldn't budge

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I had encountered this issue before. Just use below code snippet:

`.site-nav__link:hover span.site-nav__label { border-bottom: none; }`

From my code snippet. Just replace it with your div

Comment: i just replaced my div with that code snippet but it didn't seem to change the underline when you hover. Is it possible to have this only function for a specific type of link, aka when you hover over a product title?

Comment: Yes. You just have to add a function for the hyperlink of that respective div of the product title. Still, if it has not worked just upload your code on codepen and share the link.

Comment: would it be enough to copy and paste the entire theme.css file on there for you to take a peak at it?